# Show from $P_{n+1} (t) = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} t \cdot P_n(t) - \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot P_{n-1}(t)$ that $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: real-analysis

Given that, with $|x|<1$, $$(1-2xt +x^2)^{- \frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n (t) x^n, |x|<1 $$

Show from  $$P_{n+1} (t) = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} t \cdot P_n(t) - \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot P_{n-1}(t)$$ that $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. It is the $n^{th}$ Legendre polynomial, and $(1-2xt+x^2)^{-1/2}$ is the generating function of the sequence $\{P_n\}$.

I have difficulty to understand what final product is expected. How would you show this?

Thanks for your input

Comment: Find out what $P_0$ and $P_1$ are and then inductively its clear that its a polynomial in $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, suppose the induction formula holds, then we can show $P_n(t)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial of $t$ directly by an induction process, i.e., suppose $P_{k}(t)$ is of degree $k$ and $P_{k-1}(t)$ is of degree $k-1$, show that $P_{k+1}(t)$ is of degree $k+1$.

We only need to check $P_0(t)=1$ and $P_1(t)=t$, which can be derived from the series representation.

For $P_0$, set $x=0$ on the series representation.

For $P_1$, taking derivative of both sides of the series, and set $x=0$.